# Run functions asynchronously without asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I want to understand more about `asynchronous` programming and learn more about internals. As far as I know, heart of `asyncio` is `generator`. I tried to execute `worker1` and `worker2` `asynchronously` without usage of `asyncio`. Is that code really `asynchronous` ? For sure this is `dummy` implementation, but I am going in the right direction ?

```py
import typing
import socket

def make_http_request(
    *,
    host: str = 'www.google.com',
    port: int = 80,
    worker_name: str,
    return_value: typing.Any
):
    '''
    Implement this method to read HTTP response chunk by chunk (requests.get() blocks whole thread !)
    '''
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect((host, port))
    request_string = f'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {host}\r\n\r\n'
    client.send(request_string.encode())
    response_string = b''
    while True:
        response_string += client.recv(20)
        if response_string.endswith(b'\r\n\r\n'):
            break
        yield response_string
    return return_value

def async_mock_implementation(*args, **kwargs):
    '''
    generator.send(value)
        Resumes the execution and “sends” a value into the generator function. The value argument becomes the result of the current yield expression. 
        The send() method returns the next value yielded by the generator, or raises StopIteration if the generator exits without yielding another value. 
        When send() is called to start the generator, it must be called with None as the argument, because there is no yield expression that could receive the value.
    '''
    tasks_mapping: typing.Dict[str, typing.Generator] = {
        'worker1': make_http_request(worker_name='worker1', return_value=['<worker1> value']),
        'worker2': make_http_request(worker_name='worker2', return_value=['<worker2> value'])
    }
    tasks_result: typing.Dict[str, None] = dict.fromkeys(list(tasks_mapping.keys()), None)
    while True:
        keys = list(tasks_mapping.keys())
        if not keys:
            break
        for k in keys.copy():
            # Start switching between tasks ! `k` represents reference on the task !
            print(k)
            try:
                value = tasks_mapping[k].send(None) # We are doing this to wake up the generator !
            except StopIteration as exc:
                tasks_result[k] = exc.value # Once <class 'generator'> raises a `StopIteration`, returned value from `generator function` will be set on `StopIteration's` `value` attribute. 
                del tasks_mapping[k]
    print(tasks_result)

def main():
    async_mock_implementation()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can use multi-threading.

Comment: Coroutines and generators are indeed some of the lower-level concepts that power `asyncio` behind the scenes, so IMO this is a good starting point.  If you want to keep learning, you should also try to understand futures, event loops, and the `async`/`await` syntax.

Comment: An event loop based on [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) is a more fundamental underlying principle. asyncio only works because some calls are IO bound, which allows asynchronous co-operation of routines, so unless you are looking at how the IO binding is working you are really missing the core element.

Comment: @jwal Will check select module as well. Thanks for recommendation.

Comment: @varuserx select is interesting but asyncio is vastly more useful :D, as in having used it and moved on to asyncio I'd never return. It's only informative in terms of multiplexing IO signals so that the event loop can wait efficiently if everything is waiting on IO.